# C - trying to read struct from file

Tags: c, struct

I have a program with menu. Struct is called "Siunta", struct with new values called "nauja". I'm trying to write it to file and then read from file. Functions for reading and writing are provided below. The error message in compiler:

> |144|error: 'Siunta' undeclared (first use in this function)|.

What could be wrong?

writing :

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb");
struct Siunta nauja;
fwrite(&(nauja.siuntos_nr), sizeof(nauja.siuntos_nr), 1, fp);
fwrite(&(nauja.destination), sizeof(nauja.destination), 1, fp);
fwrite(&(nauja.svoris), sizeof(nauja.svoris), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

reading :

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
struct Siunta nauja2;        
fread(&nauja2, sizeof(Siunta),1,fp);    
printf("siuntos nr: %d destination: %s Svoris: %d",nauja2.siuntos_nr, nauja2.destination, nauja2.svoris);
```

Comment: Be careful about the reading/writing of the structure. Because you write it field by field, the data in the file will not have the possible padding used by the actual structure, so when you read it the result may not be what you expect. You should read and write the structure the same way, either field by field, or the whole structure, don't mix it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg made a very important point here. It's also advisable to know who might read that file. If a different architecture reads it, it may have a different padding there and writing/reading the whole structure may not be possible. Endianness would also matter. A different endian machine will have to convert the values after reading.

Answer (score 3):

The error that occurs is due to the sizeof(Siunta) that may be sizeof(struct Siunta), but you may use also sizeof(nauja2) (that might be better).

Reading your code, I see you have written some fields of the structure Siunta, but after you want read all the structure!

You have to write the structure using:

```
fwrite(&nauja, sizeof(nauja), 1, fp);
```

Then you may read:

```
fread(&nauja2, sizeof(nauja2), 1, fp);
```

Comment: Hi, i did so as you wrote above. Printf show me some do not understandable signs, digits etc. but not the correct structure element...

Comment: Could it be related to this warning? I have them for all entries of struct. warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat=]|

Comment: Reading the code you are posted, I'm not able to understand this other warning! ... In the code I see printf seems correct, but to be sure I need the declaration of the structure (I think Siunta) and one of the line that generates the warning. An hint may be that you used %c instead of %s, but I'm not sure!

Comment: this is one of the lines printf("Gavejo salis: ");
    scanf("%s", &tmp.destination);

Comment: Yes but by looking only at the line I cannot understand the declaration of the element destination! Try to remove & ... If tmp.destination is char[20] is already a pointer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `struct Siunta` instead of `Siunta` in:

```
fread(&nauja2, sizeof(Siunta),1,fp);
```

Or, you can create a typedef beforehand, like this:

```
typedef struct Siunta Siunta;
```

Comment: do not typedef struct definitions.  such typedef's clutter the code, reduce visibility, made the code harder to understand, can be (and often are) misleading, and clutter the compiler name space.

Comment: That's a valid point of view, but I don't believe struct typedefs should be unconditionally banned. I'd argue that just like goto it's a tool that can often make your code confusing, but sometimes make it more natural if you use it correctly.

Comment: It's very strange that the very hated typedefs are everywhere in the standard include files of the C! ... and also in a lot of the C++ include!!! Do we have to think the C/C++ developer are crazy? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just write the structure field by field. Also use network ordering for numbers. This will make it future proof along with putting a version number at the start.

Comment: Yes - The problem being. It does have the advantage of being able to work on multiple platforms and also take care of different versions of software

Comment: Or - force the packing ('#prgama pack'), that's what I usually do (me being lazy...) ;-)

Comment: Then the problem is processing the data in an efficient manner. Best avoid to pack data in memory. Memory is cheap

Comment: :-) I am of a generation where we counted bytes... and memory came in MBs not GBs :-)

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon - I am a lot older than that - Got 32K and a 6502A processor. But times move on.